# arithmetic operation with expr

Tags: shell-script, quoting, expr

I am doing add operation as

```
#!/bin/sh
a=10
b=20
c='expr $a + $b'
echo "$c"
echo "$a"
echo "$b"
```

but it is showing output as

```
expr $a + $b
10
20
```

what is wrong with expr

Answer (score 7):

Your example uses the wrong type of quotes:

```
a=10 b=20 c='expr $a + $b' echo "$c" echo "$a" echo "$b"
```

which should be (as a start):

```
a=10
b=20
c=`expr $a + $b`
echo "$c"
echo "$a"
echo "$b"
```

but more readable:

```
a=10
b=20
c=$(expr $a + $b)
echo "$c"
echo "$a"
echo "$b"
```

If you want to put all of those statements on a single line, separate them by semicolons:

```
a=10; b=20; c=$(expr $a + $b); echo "$c"; echo "$a"; echo "$b"
```

Comment: FYI the original wasn't on one line, but it wasn't formatted properly so the site wrapped it all up....

Comment: Thanks very much !! it works as c=$(expr $a + $b), but wondering why all study material use c='expr $a + $b ?

Comment: Some programs (un)helpfully translate quotes.  In Microsoft Word, the feature is called smart quotes.

Comment: @user183924 those are supposed to be back ticks, like the character under the ~ on most keyboards, but sure look a lot like single quotes, so if you don't know what to look for even if something else doesn't "helpfully" translate them our eyes often will, which is part of the reason for the `$()` syntax Thomas showed here

Comment: aah ok.. Thanks very much for detailed feedback..